# how to match a sentence to a cluster of keywords?

Tags: python, data, word2vec, similarity

I have a classification problem. I have clusters called 'Experience', 'Education', 'Abilities'. The labeled data (72,000+ entries with all clusters together) with two columns looks like below.

```
year of education               Education
years education                 Education
years of educational            Education
two years of education          Education
years of education beyond       Education
education four year             Education
..........
of proven sales experience      Ability
knowledge of and                Ability
experience or education high    Ability
assigned knowledge skills       Ability
accountable for driving         Ability
..........
administrative and leadership skills    Experience
advanced negotiations skills            Experience
must have keyboarding skills            Experience
must have skills                        Experience
activities preferred skills             Experience
of clinical skill                       Experience
```

I have to give a string and find out whether it belongs to either Experience or Education or Ability based on the trained model. The examples of strings.

```
string1 = "There is a requirement of four-year professional degrees"
string2 = "Able to drive the teams to higher levels"
string3 = "Must have programming experience in C, C++"
```

when I test these strings it should be able to classify the string into either of the clusters.

- What are the possible ways to train my model?
- Referring to word2vec and doc2vec, will these models work?

I couldn't find any relevant examples to train models on words and test on strings. Any ideas on how to work?

Comment: "I couldn't find any relevant examples to train model on words and test on strings." You didn't look very hard ;) This is text classification, you'll find plenty of examples.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to frame your model as text classification. Given a corpus of documents, learn the features that predict the discrete categories.

Text classification can be done by learning an embedding and training a model to learn to classify the documents into categories.

Something like this:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers                 import Activation, Dense, Embedding, Convolution1D, MaxPooling1D
from tensorflow.keras.models                 import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text     import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from tensorflow.keras.utils                  import to_categorical

docs = ['year of education',              
'years education',                 
'years of educational',            
'two years of education',          
'years of education beyond',       
'education four year',             
'of proven sales experience',      
'knowledge of and',                
'experience or education high',    
'assigned knowledge skills',       
'accountable for driving',         
'administrative and leadership skills',    
'advanced negotiations skills',            
'must have keyboarding skills',            
'must have skills',                        
'activities preferred skills',             
'of clinical skill ',]      

# Tranform string documents into numeric sequences
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=100) # Tokenizer lowercases and strips punctuation 
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X)
X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X) # Convert texts to token sequences

y = ['Education']*5
y += ['Ability']*5
y += ['Experience']*5

# Tranform string categories into numeric categories
mapping = {word: i for i,word in enumerate(y)}  # Hashing trick to encode string as category 
vec = [mapping[word] for word in y]  # Apply hashing trick
y = to_categorical(vec) # Convert numerical values into one-hot encoded values

# Create the model
model = Sequential()

# The Embedding layer is similar to word2vec
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=100, 
                    output_dim=3, 
                    input_length=4
                       ))

# Convolution layer
model.add(Convolution1D(filters=64,
                            kernel_size=2,
                            activation='relu',))
model.add(MaxPooling1D())

# The target specific output layer
model.add(Dense(units=3))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='sgd',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
model.fit(X, 
          y, 
          batch_size=256, 
          epochs=100);

# Predict the categories for new data
docs_new = ["There is a requirement of four-year professional degrees", 
         "Able to drive the teams to higher levels",
         "Must have programming experience in C, C++",]

for X_new in docs_new:
    X_new = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_new) 
model.predict(X_new)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am kind of confused by the question. But I am guessing you are asking what model to use and how to represent words.

This seems like a pretty introductory example so you may want to try simple Bag-of-words representation. Try pushing that into a Naive Bayes classifier as a first pass. If you are unhappy with the results, you can implement word2vec and more complex methods.

Comment: if it works with word2vec, please update your answer or please provide any reference link with examples where I can read and understand.

Comment: @Raady: Why do you want to use word2vec? Start with simple methods, see e.g. https://pythonmachinelearning.pro/text-classification-tutorial-with-naive-bayes/ (google text classification python for more examples)

Comment: Literally the first thing on Google under "word2vec text classification": [Link](https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-text-classification-model-comparison-and-selection-5eb066197568)